# Should I say "at the shopping" or "while shopping"?

Tags: word-choice

Can we say

> Conversation started **at** the shopping.

or

> Conversation started **while** shopping.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

"Conversation started at the shopping" is grammatically incorrect. *Shopping* is a verb, so you can't be "at" it. Of course the word "shopping" is sometimes included in a noun, for example "shopping mall".

The "correct" phrasing would depend on the *timing*. Do you intend to show that two people began a conversation *as they began* shopping, or *during their shopping*?

Your alternative "*conversation started while shopping*" implies that the subject had already started shopping *and then* the conversation began.

If you want to show the conversation began right away, you could say either:

> Conversation started when they began shopping.
>   Conversation started when they arrived at the shopping mall.

Alternatively, if you want to show that conversation began *during* shopping you could say either:

> Conversation started while they were shopping.
>   Conversation started while they were at the shopping mall.